# Ruby enumerable take first elements until condition is not met

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I built my own class and I made it enumerable and now I want to take as many elements as possible, starting from the first one, so long as let's say the sum of them isn't higher than 10. I'm leaning towards a `take_while` but I'm not sure how to write it.

If you have any other ideas I'm open to them as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question look like __write code for me__. What have you tried so far?

Comment: did you read the example for [`take_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while) in docs?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how to do something else in the block after the conditions are met, I tried with
`my_enum.take_while do |x| 
sum + x <= 10
sum += x end` (I have sum defined as 0 before that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
a = [1, 2, 13, 24, 5, 0]
sum = 0
a.take_while { |i| sum+=i; sum < 10  } 
#=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I kept testing and saw that I could write a `do..end` block with an `if` inside but your solution looks much better :)